KMP unresolved reference: String.format with wasmJS
Since enabling the wasmJS build target in my KMP project with gradle, I can no longer use String.format in my shared module.
shared/build.gradle.kts
kotlin {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalWasmDsl::class)
    wasmJs {
        browser {
            val rootDirPath = project.rootDir.path
            val projectDirPath = project.projectDir.path
            commonWebpackConfig {
                devServer = (devServer ?: KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer()).apply {
                    static = (static ?: mutableListOf()).apply {
                        // Serve sources to debug inside browser
                        add(rootDirPath)
                        add(projectDirPath)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/MainView.kt
Text(
    text = "$description (${String.format("%.2f", percentageChange)}%)", // unresolved reference: format
    fontSize = textSize
 ) 

This is the first time for me that a standard library function has disappeared when a build target is switched. I'm interested to know how this can be and what the mechanism behind this is. In my understanding there must be some calculation on what the common "std" for all platforms is but I do not understand how it works.

The problem is that your call to String.format should be in jvmMain and not commonMain, because String.format is only available on the JVM platform, since all this function does is to forward to Java's String.format method.
You will need to use a different means of formatting your string for each target platform. In your case, for wasmJs you can do ${percentageChange.toFixed(2)}%.
There is a feature request in the Kotlin issue tracker asking to make String.format available for Multiplatform. It is still open after 6 years, so don't expect it to be implemented soon.

I would fix the issue with expect and add an implementation for each platoform. But my question is one level deeper. I want to know at which level it is decided that format is not available anymore.

could you please add code to your answer and what project structure is required for it? Unfortunately I get "Unresolved reference: toFixed" in shared/src/wasmJsMain/kotlin/String.kt

@kfaria I'm sorry, I'm not a WASM or Javascript expert, I'm not sure exactly how it should be. I was only able to give vague descriptions of how it should be structured.
